# LINQ - Left Join, Group By, and Count

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have this SQL:

```
SELECT p.ParentId, COUNT(c.ChildId)
FROM ParentTable p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ChildTable c ON p.ParentId = c.ChildParentId
GROUP BY p.ParentId
```

How can I translate this into LINQ to SQL? I got stuck at the COUNT(c.ChildId), the generated SQL always seems to output COUNT(*). Here's what I got so far:

```
from p in context.ParentTable
join c in context.ChildTable on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group j2 by p.ParentId into grouped
select new { ParentId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count() }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 199, accepted):

```
from p in context.ParentTable
join c in context.ChildTable on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group j2 by p.ParentId into grouped
select new { ParentId = grouped.Key, Count = grouped.Count(t=>t.ChildId != null) }
```

Comment: OK, that works, but why? How do you think through it? How does not counting null values give us the same as COUNT(c.ChildId)? Thanks.

Comment: This is how SQL works. COUNT(fieldname) will count the rows in that field that are not null. Maybe I don't get your question, please clarify if that's the case.

Comment: I guess I always thought about it in terms of counting rows, but you are correct, only the non-null values are counted. Thanks.

Comment: .Count() will generate COUNT(*) which will count all the rows in that group, by the way.

Comment: I had the exact same problem however comparing t=>t.ChildID != null didn't work for me. The result was always a null object and Resharper complained that the expression was always true. So I used (t => t != null) and that worked for me.

Comment: You don't need "group by" here since "join into" in LINQ is essentially group join. Also, "j1", "j2" and null checking are not required either. They are extra noise. See my answer below for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 63):

Consider using a subquery:

```
from p in context.ParentTable 
let cCount =
(
  from c in context.ChildTable
  where p.ParentId == c.ChildParentId
  select c
).Count()
select new { ParentId = p.Key, Count = cCount } ;
```

---

If the query types are connected by an association, this simplifies to:

```
from p in context.ParentTable 
let cCount = p.Children.Count()
select new { ParentId = p.Key, Count = cCount } ;
```

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been a while), that query was a simplified version of a large one. If all I needed was the key and count your solution would've been cleaner / better.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense in context with original question and upvoted answers.  Additionally - if you want more than the key, you have the whole parent row to draw from.

Comment: The solution with `let` keyword will generate a subquery as same as @Mosh group joined solution.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin yes, it generates a subquery the same as the query with a subquery in my answer directly above it.

Answer (score 39):

**LATE ANSWER:**

You **shouldn't need the left join** at all if all you're doing is Count(). Note that `join...into` is actually translated to `GroupJoin` which returns groupings like `new{parent,IEnumerable<child>}` so you just need to call `Count()` on the group:

```
from p in context.ParentTable
join c in context.ChildTable on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into g
select new { ParentId = p.Id, Count = g.Count() }
```

In Extension Method syntax a `join into` is equivalent to `GroupJoin` (while a `join` without an `into` is `Join`):

```
context.ParentTable
    .GroupJoin(
                   inner: context.ChildTable
        outerKeySelector: parent => parent.ParentId,
        innerKeySelector: child => child.ParentId,
          resultSelector: (parent, children) => new { parent.Id, Count = children.Count() }
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 (from p in context.ParentTable     
  join c in context.ChildTable 
    on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into j1 
  from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty() 
     select new { 
          ParentId = p.ParentId,
         ChildId = j2==null? 0 : 1 
      })
   .GroupBy(o=>o.ParentId) 
   .Select(o=>new { ParentId = o.key, Count = o.Sum(p=>p.ChildId) })
```

Answer (score 8):

While the idea behind LINQ syntax is to emulate the SQL syntax, you shouldn't always think of directly translating your SQL code into LINQ. In this particular case, we don't need to do **group into** since **join into** is a group join itself.

Here's my solution:

```
from p in context.ParentTable
join c in context.ChildTable on p.ParentId equals c.ChildParentId into joined
select new { ParentId = p.ParentId, Count = joined.Count() }
```

Unlike the mostly voted solution here, we don't need **j1**, **j2** and null checking in **Count(t => t.ChildId != null)**