# Group by Multiple Columns and Count

Tags: linq, count, left-join, linq-group

I have Table1 and Table2 in the form of `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Both the tables have columns `Column1` and `Column2`.

I would like to do a left outer join on `Column1` and would like to get a count of the rows present in `Table2` and load the records into a DataTable.

I tried the following query

```
var query = from p in Table1
            join q in Table2 on p.Field<string>("Column1") equals q.Field<string>("Column1") into pq
            from xyz in pq.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group xyz by new { Col1 = p.Field<string>("Column1"), Col2 = p.Field<string>("Column2") } into g
            select dtFinalData.LoadDataRow(new object[]
            {
                g.Key.Col1,
                g.Key.Col2,                               
                g.Count
            }, false);
```

Since the 'g' represents the grouped data the g.count returns 1 for rows which does not have entries in Table 2. I would like to return '0' for those rows.

Input :

**Table 1**

```
Col1Val1       Col2Val1

Col1Val2       Col2Val2
```

**Table 2**

```
Col1Val1       Col2Val1

Col1Val1       Col2Val1
```

**Current Output :**

```
Col1Val1        Col2Val1    2

Col2Val2        Col2Val2    1
```

**Expected Results :**

```
Col1Val1        Col2Val1    2

Col2Val2        Col2Val2    0
```

I have looked at [LINQ - Left Join, Group By, and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count) but I could not apply the same into my query ...

Can you help me fix this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` it be so:

```
from p in Table1
let p1 = p.Field<string>("Column1")
let p2 = p.Field<string>("Column2") 
let qs = 
  from q in Table2
  where p1 == q.Field<string>("Column1")
  select q
let qCount = qs.Count()
select dtFinalData.LoadDataRow(new object[]
{
  p1,
  p2,
  qCount
}, false);
```

Since I didn't join, I don't have to group.  Each result row corresponds to a row in Table1.

---

Here's a GroupJoin solution:

```
from p in Table1 
let pkey = new { c1 = p.Field<string>("Column1"), c2 = p.Field<string>("Column2") }
join q in Table2 on pkey equals
  new { c1 = q.Field<string>("Column1"), c2 = q.Field<string>("Column2") }
  into qs
select dtFinalData.LoadDataRow(new object[] 
{ 
  pkey.c1, 
  pkey.c2, 
  qs.Count() 
}, false);
```

And here's a Join and Group solution.

```
from p in Table1 
let pkey = new { c1 = p.Field<string>("Column1"), c2 = p.Field<string>("Column2") }
join q in Table2 on pkey equals
  new { c1 = q.Field<string>("Column1"), c2 = q.Field<string>("Column2") }
  into right
from q in right.DefaultIfEmpty()
group q by pkey into g
select dtFinalData.LoadDataRow(new object[] 
{ 
  g.Key.c1, 
  g.Key.c2, 
  g.Count(q => q != null) 
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks David! Your query works. I am still curious to find out if there is way to do something similar to the following SQL query
select a.Column1,a.Column2,Count(b.Column1) 
   from table1 a 
    Left outer join table2 b on a.Column1 = b.Column1 and a.Column2 = b.Column2
group By a.Column1,a.Column2

Comment: Added more solutions... it's worth noting that the last solution will give different results if there are duplicates in Table1.