# How to create Linq2Sql query that will group records from linked table and calculate 2 count fields

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-sql, bltoolkit

Here I found how to join tables using Linq2Sql and count amount of linked records [LINQ - Left Join, Group By, and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count)

I've implemented it and it works ok for me: the following expression

```
var v = from c in db.GetTable<Country>()
        join t0 in db.GetTable<Team>() on c.Id equals t0.CountryId into t1
        from team in t1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        group team by c.Id into teamsGrouped
        select new CountryTeamsInfo
            {
                CountryId = teamsGrouped.Key,
                TeamsTotal = teamsGrouped.Count(),
                // TeamsWithoutOwnerFree = teamsGrouped.Count(t => t.OwnerId==0)
            }
            ;
         List<CountryTeamsInfo> res = v.ToList();
```

generates the following query:

```
SELECT c.Id, Count(*) as c1
FROM countries c
LEFT JOIN teams t1 ON c.Id = t1.Country
GROUP BY c.Id
```

In fact I need also to count those linker records that has OwnerId field non-equal to 0.

It looks like I should just uncomment that line in linq expression (TeamsWithoutOwnerFree = teamsGrouped.Count(t => t.OwnerId==0)), but that doesn't work, attempt to execute that causes an error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary

The query don't come to SQL log file, and I can't examine it in the debugger.

What should be a proper way to count those lines from 'teams' table that meet additional criteria.

P.S. if it matters, I use C# 4.0, MySql 5.1 and BLToolkit 4.1

Comment: Strange, it should work. What is the stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is query that works in my environment:

```
from c in db.GetTable<Country>()
where c.Allowed
select new CountryTeamsInfo
{
    CountryId = c.Id,
    TeamsTotal = db.GetTable<Team>().Count(t => t.CountryId == c.Id && t.Allowed),
    TeamsHasOwner = db.GetTable<Team>().Count(t => t.CountryId == c.Id && t.Allowed && t.OwnerId != 0),
}
```

Not the best solution (I need to repeat teams selection criteria t.Allowed in each sub-query), but still works well and generated SQL is good.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using [`GroupJoin()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for your query:

```
var result = db.GetTable<Country>()
               .GroupJoin(db.GetTable<Team>(),
                   c => c.Id,
                   t => t.CountryId,
                   (country, teams) => new
                   {
                       CountryId = country.Id,
                       TeamsTotal = teams.Count(),
                       TeamsWithoutOwnerFree = teams.Count(t => t.OwnerId == 0)
                   })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, will try. Could you please also advise "translation" from extension methods into linq2sql for the GroupJoin? Thank you

Comment: @Budda, I don't quite understand the question - what do you mean by "translation from extension methods into linq2sql"?

Comment: I just wanted to write the same using Linq2Sql syntax (as in my original post), not syntax that is based on the ExtensionMethods, but that is not a big deal.

Comment: I've checked you suggestion and it looks like resolved execution problem. But the generated query still doesn't have component to calculate 'TeamsWithoutOwnerFree'...

Comment: it looks like I should write an additional "query" to fetch those teams that have OwnerId==0. Will try

Answer (score 0):

Due to RePierre help I was able to find the proper query:

```
var v = db.GetTable<Country>().Where(country => country.Allowed)
                    .GroupJoin(
                        db.GetTable<Team>(),
                        country => country.Id,
                        team => team.CountryId,
                        (country, teams) => new CountryTeamsInfo
                                                {
                                                    CountryId = country.Id,
                                                    TeamsTotal = teams.Count(),
                                                    TeamsWithoutOwnerFree = teams.Count(t => t.OwnerId != 0),
                                                }
                    ).GroupJoin(
                        db.GetTable<Team>().Where(te=>te.OwnerId==0),
                        cti => cti.CountryId,
                        team => team.CountryId,
                        (cti, teams) => new CountryTeamsInfo
                        {
                            CountryId = cti.CountryId,
                            TeamsTotal = cti.TeamsTotal,
                            TeamsWithoutOwnerFree = teams.Count(t => t.OwnerId != 0),
                        }
                    )
                    ;
```

My concern is it uses 2 sub-queries... will try to optimize that. Any ideas would be great

P.S. Actually, generated SQL query looks ugly as well:

```
SELECT
cti.Id as Id1,
cti.c1 as c11,
(
    SELECT
        Count(*)
    FROM
        teams te
    WHERE
        cti.Id = te.Country AND te.User = 0
) as c2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        country.Id,
        (
            SELECT
                Count(*)
            FROM
                teams t1
            WHERE
                country.Id = t1.Country
        ) as c1
    FROM
        countries country
    WHERE
        country.allow
```

Comment: You should not be concerned that it uses two subqueries because linq to sql uses defered execution - meaning that only one query goes to the database. From this point of view, you can split your queries however you like to maintain your coding style and improve readability.

Comment: if there's a parent-child relationship between `Countries` and `Teams` you could try this approach http://pastebin.com/KzG68fEP