# c# DataTable difference using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 datatables.

**dtTable1:**

```
id    Name
---    ----
1     AAA
2     BBB
```

**dtTable2:**

```
id
---
2
```

The output needs to be table1 without the row with id=2.

How can I do this using Linq?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check this SO post: [Is there a “not equal” in a linq join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count)

```
var filteredDataTable = tableA.Except(tableB);
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

You may get a list of IDs from second DataTAble like:

```
var tempList = (from d in dt2.AsEnumerable()
            select d.Field<int>("ID")).ToList();
```

Later you can use `!Contains` to check Not In from the first datatable like:

```
var result = from t in dt1.AsEnumerable()
             where !tempList.Contains(t.Field<int>("ID"))
             select t;
```