# LINQ Query Not Querying as Expected

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I was wandering if someone can explain to me why this query doesn't act like the SQL Left join, I cant seem to work out why. I have been doing a bit of hunting and I can't seem to work it out. As far as I can tell it should.
I.e. In a table with 5 Active Customers it will only return 2 of those Customers instead of all 5; 2 with values and 3 with either null or 0?

```
var results = from c in DataContext.Customers
              where c.Active
              join j1 in
              (from i in DataContext.Invoice where i.State== "Pending" &&
               i.InvoiceDate.Date >= From.Date && i.InvoiceDate.Date <= To.Date 
               group i by i.Customer into x 
                      select new { x.Key, Total = x.Count() }) on a equals j1.Key
                      select new { c, j1.Total };
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, there is a good example on how to perform Left Outer Joins in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx I think you are missing the fact that you have to call the DefaultIfEmpty method on each sequence of matching elements from the group join

Comment: Awesome between your comment and the anwser I was able to work it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using DefaultIfEmpty() method you can do it.
Try this code
i have implementd your problem's solution
revert me if it worked

```
var results = from c in DataContext.Customers
                  where c.Active
                  join j1 in
                  (from i in DataContext.Invoice where i.State== "Pending" &&
                   i.InvoiceDate.Date >= From.Date && i.InvoiceDate.Date <= To.Date 
                   group i by i.Customer into x 
                          select new { x.Key, Total = x.Count() }) on a equals j1.Key into j3
                                from k in j3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new { c, k.Total };
```

Comment: Awesome thanks got it to work although just one thing (just trivial) but changing " select new {c, k.Total} " to "select new {c, TotalInvoices = k.Total==null?0:k.Total } " stops the null exception

Answer (score 0):

I would try `DefaultIfEmpty()` method on your `j1` subquery, because you aren't allowing the query to join on null values.

See the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count?rq=1) for examples.