# LINQ Entity Framework 4 SELECT COUNT LEFT OUTER JOIN IN GROUP BY

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Using LINQ to Entities I'm having trouble getting a count of child objects given a list of parent ids. Here's how I'd do it in straight SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(Child.ParentId) ,Parent.Parentd
FROM Parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN Child ON Child.ParentId = Parent.ParentId
WHERE
    Parent.ParentId IN (
        8417
        ,118458
        ,120567
        ,121596
        )
GROUP BY Parent.ParentId
```

Here's what I've tried in LINQ to Entities:

```
var counts = from Parent in context.Parents
    join Child in context.Children on Parent.ParentId equals Child.ParentId 
    into children
    from jn in children.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where iEnumerableParentIds.Contains(parent.parentId)
    group parent by parent.parentId
    into g
    select new {count = g.Count(), parentId = g.Key};
```

This is pretty close but I'm counting the grouped parent instead of the child which gives me a count of 1 when there are no children on the parent.

Comment: Do you have a "navigation property" for your `Parent` entity, like a `Children` property?

Comment: no. this project was a "data-first" setup and there was not a formal sql foreign key relationship setup. we never setup the foreign key on the db because we knew there were orphans that we could not eliminate from the child table

Comment: looks like the answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count?rq=1 Trying it out now...

Comment: the answer to the older question worked

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the `group`ing source here:

```
             group new { parent, jn } by parent.parentId
             into g
             select new {count = g.Select(x => x.jn).Count(), parentId = g.Key};
```

Answer (score 0):

var counts = from Parent in context.Parents
    join Child in context.Children on Parent.ParentId equals Child.ParentId 
    into children
    where iEnumerableParentIds.Contains(parent.parentId)
    select new {count = children.Count(), parentId = Parent.ParentId};

With out testing (responding from my iPod ;)), I am pretty sure this will give you the results you want. I can't remember exactly what I do off the top of my head but I think that should work.  Basically, you've already grouped the join so you shouldn't have to group everything a second time.