# join, group by and count sql to linq conversion

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Avalied
FROM LeaveMaster as lm
JOIN LeaveSubsidary as ls 
ON lm.TransMasterId = ls.TransMasterId
WHERE lm.SystemCode = 'abc123' AND lm.EmployeeCode = '0014' AND lm.Status ='Approved'
Group by ls.Leave_Type
```

How would you convert the above sql query to linq? Thanks :)

Edit :

```
from p in db.PY_LeaveTransactionMasterTAB.AsEnumerable()
join e in db.PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB.AsEnumerable() on p.LV_TransMasterId equals e.LV_TransMasterId into grp
where p.SystemCode == SysCode && p.EmployeeCode == EmpCode && p.Status == "Approved"
group grp by e.Leave_Type // This line is invalid Why?
```

The above is what I have tried so far, why can't I do `e.Leave_Type` or what is the right way to do `group grp by e.Leave_Type`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - Left Join, Group By, and Count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count)

Comment: @GurV I've already seen that link, take a look at my edited part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
(from p in db.PY_LeaveTransactionMasterTAB
join e in db.PY_LeaveTransactionSubsidaryTAB on p.LV_TransMasterId equals e.LV_TransMasterId 
where p.SystemCode == SysCode && p.EmployeeCode == EmpCode && p.Status == "Approved"
group new {p,e} by new {e.Leave_Type } into gr
select new 
{
   Leave_Type = gr.Key.Leave_Type ,
   Count = gr.Count()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: That's the Answer!