# LINQ join Table on Variable

Tags: linq

I have this query in LINQ which I aggregate on the ID and sales:

```
var resultsales = (from so in _salesRepo.QueryNoTracking
                   group so by so.Id into TotaledOrders
                   select new Example
                          {
                             Id = TotaledOrders.Key.ToString(),
                             TotaledValue = TotaledOrders.Sum(s => s.TotalCost).ToString(),
                             Orders = TotaledOrders.ToString()
                          }).ToList();
```

Now I have this table (`customerinfo`) that I want to join:

```
ID Name Address 
---------------
1  .... .....
2  .... .....
```

What's the correct way to outer join with my new table stored as a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695506/linq-left-join-group-by-and-count

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL / EF / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x?